# Is it possible to change which SE site a chat room I own is tied to?

Tags: discussion, support

I recently created the chat room [Liftoff](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/51954/liftoff#), intending it to be a tied to Area 51. However, something must have gotten mixed up while I was creating it, and it ended up being tied to History SE instead of Area 51 SE.

My question is, can I (or a moderator) change which site this room is tied to, or do I just have to re-create this room, this time with the proper tie-in?

Answer (score 1):

The only things useful I can do from the mod interface there (that I can see) is delete the room, and/or move the messages.

Since that room only has a single message, one would imagine it makes much more sense to just create yourself the proper room and copy the text of your one message back there yourself.

However, since that site doesn't appear to have a main chatroom, I seriously doubt anyone will ever go into its chat interface to see it. Probably better to ask your question on its Meta.